# Получить размер текстуры в памяти

Tags: c++, 3d, directx, direct3d

Загружаю текстуру функцией:

```
HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(dxdev, file.c_str(), &Texture);
```

, где Texture - это загруженная текстура. Как узнать её размер в памяти(в байтах)?

Comment: Эта функция загружает текстуру в управляемый пулл ресурсов, соответственно объем занимаемой памяти (как видео, так и обычной) может меняться. Кроме того при использовании сжатия он может быть урезан. Отмечу, что `D3DXCreateTextureFromFile` является устаревшей и использовать ее не стоит (как и directx9 в целом).

Comment: VTT полностью согласен про DirectX 9, но увы,я нахожусь только в процессе изучения английского языка, а Dx 11 - 12 - вся литература на английском. Быть может посоветуете? Про функцию знаю, есть версия Ex, это я просто пример привел. В целом вопрос считается решенным, пересмотрю архитектуру класса.

Comment: Я посоветую браться за английский и учить его по ходу дела. Применяя язык на практике он будет усваиваться шустрее, нежили при изучении всяких учебников или курсов. Вместо литературу (которой для начинающих как-то мало) посоветую [http://www.rastertek.com/tutindex.html](http://www.rastertek.com/tutindex.html).

Comment: Большое спасибо!